# Trouble with ProxyPass of REMOTE_USER from nginx to Django

Tags: django, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an nginx web server that's configured with client certificate authentication. Once authenticated, I proxy requests to a uWSGI Django application server. I've set-up my Django application to perform authentication using REMOTE_USER (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/auth-remote-user/), however it doesn't seem to be working as I receive the "'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable" error from Django.

I'm assuming that I'm missing something in my nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my.website.net;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.website.net/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.website.net/privkey.pem;
  ssl_verify_client on;
  ssl_verify_depth 2;
  ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cas.pem;
  proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-Serial $ssl_client_serial;
  proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-Verify $ssl_client_verify;
  proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-S-DN   $ssl_client_s_dn;
  proxy_set_header X-Remote-User $remote_user;
  proxy_set_header REMOTE_USER $remote_user;

  location / {
    root /var/www/my.website.net;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }

  location /django {
    proxy_set_header Host 10.101.10.228;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";

    proxy_pass http://10.101.10.228:8000/webapp;
    proxy_redirect http://10.101.10.228/django/ https://my.website.net/django/;

  }

}
```

I've also tried utilizing the nginx uwsgi_* directives with no luck:

```
upstream django {
  server 10.101.10.228:8000;
}
location /django {
  include         uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass django;
  uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /webapp;
  uwsgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
  uwsgi_param X-REMOTE-USER $remote_user;
}
```

Is there something that appears to be missing?

Comment: It should definitely work with uwsgi_params and not via headers. However, is $remote_user populated, because client certificate authentication isn't the same thing as Basic authentication. You can log the variable to the nginx log if unsure, using [log_format](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`$remote_user`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_remote_user) nginx variable is being populated only for HTTP Basic Authentication. You can rely on [`$ssl_client_s_dn`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#var_ssl_client_s_dn) variable to use the client DN as the username:

```
proxy_set_header Remote_User $ssl_client_s_dn;
```

or

```
uwsgi_param REMOTE_USER $ssl_client_s_dn;
```

You can use the [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) block to retreive only some specific field from the client DN, for example to get the CN (canonical name) only:

```
map $ssl_client_s_dn $remote_user_cn {
    ~,CN=(?<CN>[^,]+) $CN;
}
```

and then use the `$remote_user_cn` variable as the username.

Comment: You're right, $remote_user was not getting set automatically, so I used $ssl_client_s_dn (using uwsgi_pass). Thanks!